# fakeroot and package building

Tags: application-development, dbus, avahi, pbuilder

We have developed a network pub/sub communication suite. It is in use across a number of different applications and domains, most notably on our payloads aboard the International Space Station (ISS). Ubuntu is our primary development and deployment system. All our code is nicely packaged. In the process of building the packages, I would like to run the test suites included in each code base. However...

Our communication protocol uses Avahi, which in turn uses DBus. Thus our tests use DBus. When building a package, "fakeroot" is invoked to solve a number of problems. However, it introduces a problem that I've been unable to solve. When our tests run without fakeroot, we see something like this:

```
[pid  3286] sendto(12, "AUTH EXTERNAL 31303030\r\n", 24, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 24
[pid  3286] read(12, "OK 38b4600ae82865f9eba81cb700000"..., 2048) = 37
```

When the same test is run using fakeroot, we see something like this:

```
[pid  3280] sendto(12, "AUTH EXTERNAL 30\r\n", 18, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 18
[pid  3280] read(12, "REJECTED EXTERNAL DBUS_COOKIE_SH"..., 2048) = 46
```

It turns out that the DBus authentication is simply using the ASCII code of the string representation of the UID for the user. When run normally, the UID is 1000, '1' is 31, '0' is 30; therefore the authentication token for UID 1000 is 31303030. Under fakeroot, the program thinks its UID is 0 and sends the token 30. This is rejected and the whole mess fails.

This is connecting to the system DBus and not a session DBus, so I can't just start a new instance inside fakeroot. I've gone through our code, the Avahi code and the DBus code, and don't see any way to work around this.

So finally the question - Is there a way to run tests during package building without the fakeroot wrapper? I really want the tests to run, since the code is submitted to a buildbot system that has a wide variety of Linux distributions and versions. This provides much better test coverage than just running the tests on my development system.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed a few test suites which get confused when you run them under fakeroot. You can disable fakeroot for those with something like that in `debian/rules`:

```
override_dh_auto_test:
            env -u LD_PRELOAD dh_auto_test
```

This is right if your test suite is simply "make check" and you use reasonably modern packaging. The gist is to unset `$LD_PRELOAD`.

However, please note that you can *not* rely on the system D-BUS running during package build. Init scripts and the like are usually disabled in build environments using `policy-rc.d`, so if your tests want a system bus they need to start one themselves (dbus-launch, and `export DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`).